# Battery Status notifier

Tags: arduino-nano, battery

I am new to Arduino, and I am aware that unlike Raspberry Pi you do not have a full blown OS with many custom applications running concurrently. 
I plan to start an Arduino project with an Arduino NANO that will need to be portable, and include batteries. How may I get the battery status information without disrupting the rest of the functionality?

Comment: What do you mean "without disrupting the rest of the functionality"?

Comment: @AndrewPaes Well. I am new to Arduino, so I dont know if I can run more than one scripts concurrently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use analogRead to measure the voltage on the battery. You might have to use the internal 1.1V reference to get a good reading.

Don't write any blocking code and the processes won't interfere with each other. That means no long for or while loops waiting for something to complete and absolutely no delay.

Comment: To read the battery voltage using the 1.1V reference, you need to put the battery voltage through a resistor divider, to lower the voltage to between 0V and 1.1V. To prevent these resistors from draining the battery too hard, you need to select an appropriate high value. High enough, to not drain the battery to fast, low enough to not get influenced by the sample-and-hold capacitor and the input impedance of the ADC. Adding a small capacitor will also help with high value resistors.

Comment: Or, if the battery is powering the ATMega directly you just read the 1.1v reference using the battery as the ADC reference then calculate what the battery voltage must be to give the reading you got for the 1.1v reference.